# How to prevent polygon overlap in 3D graphics

Tags: java, swing, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have been drawing 3D graphics using the graphics.fillPolygon() method in Java. It has worked well for me so far. I can rotate the graphics by dragging my mouse across the screen, and I can zoom in and out of my graphics.

My one issue though, is finding a way to draw the polygons in the correct order so that the background polygons are not drawn on top of the foreground polygons. I know that the answer to my problem is common knowledge to the 3D graphics programmer; Some people have told me to use OpenGL, but that is too much for me to learn right now; I just want to create basic 3D graphics. I am looking for a mathematical procedure to organize my polygons in the order that they should be drawn, (from back to front).

I have thought about just taking the average distance to all points of each polygon, but that is an unreliable method. I have been using trigonometry for all of my methods, but I am starting to learn some linear algebra concepts; The use of vectors may be helpful in finding which polygons lie in front.

Comment: I don't know how much you are willing to go deep into this but , you can get much from BSP trees in regard to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

@Raisintoe, In computer science, binary space partitioning (BSP) is a method for recursively subdividing a space into convex sets by hyperplanes. This subdivision gives rise to a representation of objects within the space by means of a tree data structure known as a BSP tree.

Binary space partitioning was developed in the context of 3D computer graphics,[1](http://www.bluesnews.com/abrash/chap64.shtml) where the structure of a BSP tree allows spatial information about the objects in a scene that is useful in rendering, **such as their ordering from front-to-back with respect to a viewer at a given location**, **to be accessed rapidly.** Other applications include performing geometrical operations with shapes (constructive solid geometry) in CAD,[3] collision detection in robotics and 3-D video games, ray tracing and other computer applications that involve handling of complex spatial scenes.

See the [Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)

This approach has been used by video games mega tubes such as Quake. You can find more about it in this [excellent article by Michael Abrash](http://www.bluesnews.com/abrash/chap64.shtml) where he explains how they used BSP tree in Quake to determine Quake's visible surfaces.

I Hope this helps

Comment: OK, I have been reading the articles that you posted. This is exciting for me to see; I knew that I needed to order the polygons from back-to-front, (or front-to-back), but I never could figure out how to calculate which polygons were in front, and which were in back. I think I am seeing now, how to use hyperplanes to order my geometry. The idea is to split up every polygon by hyperplanes, and these hyperplanes are set on every edge of every polygon, orthogonal to the viewer's plane. Is that correct?

Comment: And by orthogonal to the viewer's plane, I mean that the geometry is already static, (the distance scaling has already been performed, so the viewer's point can be considered a plane).

Comment: From there (Once the polygons are split), I guess I could take the average distance to the points of the new polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I do agree, OpenGL is really complex, and especially modern openGL that forces you to use shaders always can get more in your way of getting things done, than actually helping you. But openGl solves this problem for you. It draws each pixel of the polygon with it's depth value. When you draw the second polygon, the pixel is only updated when it's depth value is closer to the camera than the old one. You can do the same, and you will have a pixel perfect result.

side note: Modern games engines even prefer rendering from the front to the back, because then the expensive pixel calculation in the fragment shader can be skipped for pixels that would be overdrawn anyway.

side note 2: actually you have to enable the depth test and explicitly tell, that you want the closest pixels.

Comment: I like that method! But by drawing pixels one at a time using only Java, I will bog  down the processor, right?

Comment: even in java you can write a reasonable fast software rasterizer, as long as you do not have too much geometry. But it's not an easy task, especially, because polygons that touch each other may not overlap or leave a gap.  If you want to use Java, the easiest method to try things out with polygons in 3d is probably processing (processing.org)

Comment: OK, well, considering also that my main focus on this project is to animate colors, (not motion, except in a few cases), I think it should work very well to create a map of visible pixels once every time the display is rotated. Then I can reuse that map to update the colors of those pixels during animation.